# Problems Installing Maven, tried everything and cant get it to work

Tags: java, maven

I have followed multiple installation tutorials on installing the latest version of Maven. I have added all the correct environment variables and updated the system variables. Here is what I have:

This is my path for Maven's bin.

```
C:\Program Files\ApacheSoftwareFoundation\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin
M2 = %M2_HOME%\bin
M2_HOME =  C:\Program Files\ApacheSoftwareFoundation\apache-maven-3.2.3
```

and my system variable looks something like this

```
%M2% is appended to the end with a ; before it of course.
```

and yes I have the latest Java JDK with the JAVA_HOME enviroment variable.

No matter what I try I always get the same thing in the console:

> 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: As shown, both the M2_HOME and M2 variables have 'bin' at the end.  M2_HOME should not include the 'bin' part.

Comment: @user944849 I have tried it without the \bin and one tutorial said to try it this way.

Comment: M2_HOME should not have the 'bin' part.  This is also noted in another answer below.  After you changed the variables, did you open a new console window?

Comment: @user944849 Yes, after all changes I open a new window. I have removed the bin part and it still doesnt work. A tutorial I watched suggested the bin idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it to PATH variable ([tutorial](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml))
or just

```
set PATH=%PATH%;path_to_maven_bin
```

Comment: Already tried a separate Path Variable like this, does not work for me.

Comment: Open console. Then execute `set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin"` and in same console type mvn.

Comment: Okay I got this working now. so do I need to do this everytime I want to use maven?

Comment: No. You can set it system wide as in tutorial I post. Dont forget about `"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting paths from command prompt, enclose the Maven installation directory inside double quotes `"{Maven path}"` since there are spaces in the path of Maven installation directory.

Comment: I tried this, would I include the brackets as well or just the quotations. With the brackets it does not work, and would I enclose the entire path or just the part with the spaces? @Pam

Comment: No, not the brackets. It will look like this: `"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin""`

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1) M2_HOME must point to `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.3\` (no \bin part). This is the correct usage, which may be expected by your IDE or other tools. M2_HOME is also synonymous with MAVEN_HOME
2) Add `%M2_HOME%\bin` to the end of your %PATH% - the %PATH% holds the locations of the executable programs (exe, com, bat, ...) which Windows scans when commands are not fully qualified, e.g. when you type

`> mvn install`

Windows will actually execute this

`> C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin\mvn.bat install`

Comment: My m2 variable adds the %M2_HOME%\bin to the end of the system path. Still doesnt work for me, I have no idea why this is not working.

Comment: when you type > `path` in your console do you see the entry "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin" anywhere in the list? If not, then your PATH variable is not set correctly, check for syntax errors, typos, etc ..

Comment: Okay, checking for errors, getting rid of the spaces in the directory.

Comment: I have checked everything an there are no errors. I am completely lost in this crap.

Comment: Do you actually see the maven entry in your PATH?

Answer (score 0):

Running command prompt as an administrator might help you see that maven is installed.